# accessing openshift console running inside boot2docker on windows machine gives timeout on 10.0.2.15

Tags: windows, boot2docker, openshift-origin

i want to play a little bit with openshift origin on my windows 7 machine.
therefore i have installed boot2docker.
for installation of openshift-origin i first did a `boot2docker ssh`.
inside the boot2docker vm i followed the instructions from [Openshift Getting Started](https://github.com/openshift/origin#getting-started).
i successfully got the openshift-origin container running.

now then i want to access the openshift console from https://localhost:8443/console i get redirected to the openshift authentication service on https://10.0.2.15:8443/oauth.
unfortunately this gives me a timeout in my windows browser.

Comment: Is the IP of your boot2docker instance 10.0.2.15?  If not, you may need to add a parameter to the docker run command - --master=<ip of boot2docker node>

Comment: @Clayton the boot2docker instance is running under 192.168.59.103

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these steps?

Start boot2docker

`boot2docker up`

Get docker server IP (assume 192.168.59.103). Make sure you can `ping` it from your host machine.

`boot2docker ip`

Launch the OpenShift server in a Docker container

`docker run -d --name "openshift-origin" --net=host --privileged \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /tmp/openshift:/tmp/openshift \
openshift/origin start`

Open https://192.168.59.103:8443/

Turn off or edit docker server firewall if any.

`boot2docker ssh`

`sudo iptables -L -n`

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8442 -j ACCEPT`

`sudo service iptables save`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i tried it, but unfortunately had no success. my impression is, that a route from the host to the 10.0.2.x network is missing somehow...